# Uninstall php centos

Tags: php

I compiled my php and installed (i use centos 5.3) and now i want to remove it, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normaly if you self compile you can give an option named --prefix=PREFIX to the configure script. If you did something like this,

```
configure --prefix=/usr/local/php
```

than everything is install under /usr/local/php

Normally if you do not give any options, Software is installed under /usr/local.
There in lib, bin, sbin, etc ... 
You have do delete everything which belongs to the package by hand.

Next time take care about the --prefix. If you had used it, you only need to remove the basedir given to prefix and eveything is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo make uninstall` in the same directory where you did `make install` :)
Some Makefiles do support it.